# find similarity in mysql columns

Tags: mysql, similarity

I have been asked to fetch data from Mysql-Table where Firstname and Lastname column contains similiar or alike values.
So far i have tried to use soundex expression

```
select * from table where soundex(firstname) = soundex(lastname)
```

but there are many which do not have any similarity and there are many which hasn't been found. So the gathered results are not really satisfactorily.

I have to mention, that our lastname and firstname values are mostly strong international..

Anyway, the question is: Is there an simple approach to find the rows without crafting around?

Answer (score 0):

U could try:
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastname LIKE ('%' || firstname || '%') OR firstname LIKE '%' || lastname || '%'
or something alike